# Meaning of "mongólica"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, definiciones

What does it mean if a person from Spain calls a girl "mongólica"?

> Susan es *mongólica*.

What does this mean exactly.

Comment: Esta pregunta roza un poco lo off-topic. Lo suyo habría sido buscar [mongólico/a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pe8WQle) en el diccionario, y/o [mongolismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pe9FnBx), y quizá luego pedir una aclaración sobre el uso. Siéntete bienvenida a [Spanish.se], pero visita por favor las secciones [tour], [help] y [ask] para hacerte una idea de cómo funciona este sitio.

Comment: Example: https://www.elheraldo.co/frases-que-nunca-debe-decirle-una-mujer-15725

Comment: In Argentina the variant "mogólico/a" is much more used.

Answer (score 6):

That's a derogatory term for a person who is a bit "dumb". The literal meaning can be found here:

> [mongólico, ca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pe8WQle)
>
> 3. adj. Que padece mongolismo. U. t. c. s.

Mongolismo refers means "Down's Syndrome".

So when a person uses the term "mongóloco/a", they don't mean literally that the other person sufers "Down's Syndrome" but that the person has reduced mental capacities.

Comment: Obviously this applies if the person doesn't have Down's syndrome, otherwise is just the colloquial way to refer to that condition. If the person does **not** have the condition and it is **called that**, then is like calling that person dumb or stupid which obviously is very rude.

Comment: @DGaleano Actually, today, that sounds more "rude" than "colloquial" (to allude to a person with  Down's syndrome), even in informal settings. The informal normal/polite way is "Susa es Down".

Comment: @leonbloy Agree. Colloquial if you don't use it in front of the relatives to the person with the condition or anyone that cares. If the relatives are around then it would not be "politically correct" and might be rude.